# Multi-module Maven projects

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm trying to get a Maven setup going. My project layout is simple:

```
+
+--- libA
+--- libB
+--- projX
+--- projY
```

`libA` and `libB` (actually, about 5 of them) are shared code among the projects. `projX` and `projY` (actually, about 10)  are standalone applications with a `Main` each.

My requirements are simple:

1) Be able to run projX and projY in Eclipse
2) Compile standalone JARs (with dependencies) for projX and projY *with single commands* each
3) DRY

I current have a working setup from my predecessor. It has a `pom.xml` file per library, which is fine, but two `pom.xml` files per project, which is not. One of them does not even `compile`, but is needed by the other for `compile assembly:single`. The two files are almost duplicates of eachother, and adding a new library to a project requires changes in 3-4 different places.

I have tried various things. Surprisingly, adding a super-parent `pom.xml` in the root was the easiest. That took care of project-wide settings such as UTF-8 source file encoding and whatnot. What did not work was everything else. Between POMs not being able to refer to eachother unless certain modifications are made, refusing to compile source folders when they are, insisting on a local repository which is ever-empty or requiring absolute paths otherwise, I was not able to meet the requirements I listed. This is despite reading the official documentation and scouring for examples online.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, this shouldn't be too complicated with Maven. The main idea is to put most of the redundant information in the parent (for the sake of simplicity we'll use only one parent) and then have the child modules reference the parent.

This brings the advantage of having most of the "configurable" settings in one place and limit the amount of redundancy.

[See this link for information regarding the different forms of inheritance in Maven](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance)

The structure of your projects should be something like this:

```
+
     pom.xml (root)
+--- libA
     +--- src
         +---main
             +---java
             +---resources
     pom.xml
+--- libB
     +--- src
         +---main
             +---java
             +---resources
     pom.xml
+--- projX
     +--- src
         +---main
             +---java
             +---resources
     pom.xml
+--- projY
     +--- src
         +---main
             +---java
             +---resources
     pom.xml
```

[See this link regarding standard Maven layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

You'll have 3 types of pom.xml (1 per project/library)

1. The parent root project (listing all the 'modules' and providing all inheritable settings like dependency versions, plugin versions and configuration, properties, etc...)

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <properties>
        <compiler.source>1.6</compiler.source>
        <compiler.target>1.6</compiler.target>
        <source.encoding>UTF-8</source.encoding>
        <resource.encoding>UTF-8</resource.encoding>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>libA</module>
        <module>projX</module>
    </modules>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Here put all the dependencies of all your project with groupId/artifactId/version-->
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <!-- Here put all your plugins with groupId/artifactId/version and configuration -->
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${compiler.source}</source>
                        <target>${compiler.target}</target>
                        <encoding>${source.encoding}</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>${resource.encoding}</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>build-resources</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

2. One pom.xml per library (libA, libB, etc...)

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>libA</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Here list all the actual dependencies but only groupId and artifactId 
            (versions are all put in the parent) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>...</groupId>
            <artifactId>...</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

3. One pom.xml per project (projX, projY, etc...) and here we'll also add the maven-assembly to the build

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>projX</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Here list all the actual dependencies but only groupId and artifactId (versions are all put in the parent) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
            <artifactId>libA</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin> 
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> 
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId> 
            </plugin> 
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In this configuration, maven-assembly is attached to the phase "package" which means that by calling `mvn package` in your root project, you will have all jar's and jar-with-dependencies build in one go.

Comment: I have started testing this and I think I am as far as being able to build individual projects with `clean compile assembly:single -pl proj -am`. I'll continue testing tomorrow.

Comment: @aib I slightky edited the root pom.xml to add an `executions` XML-block in the maven-assembly plugin (I omitted by mistake). This would allow you to build everything in one go by just typing `mvn package` in the root project.

Comment: Ahh, excellent addition. Thank you, everything seems to be working smoothly with this project setup. Though I think I'll still use -pl; every project has its own CI job. Or, is there a better way to build a single project (JAR with dependencies)? Note that I'm not using any fancy build mechanism -Maven plugins etc. go unmaintainable quite fast-, I'll just need a command line. `mvn clean package -pl projX -am` looks like it could do the trick.

Comment: @aib, the setup you use highly depends of your objectives. If the number of project is only going to grow, and everything is changing all the time, it might be easier to have evrything built in one go (avoiding the need to recreate new jobs for new projects); the downside is that builds can get lengthy. On the other hand, if you have only have a limited set of projects and you mostly need to build projects one by one, your command line is just fine.

Comment: Great. Thanks for all your advice.

Answer (score 1):

You will need 3 pom.xml files one for parent project and one for each child project. You will have 3 separate projects. In parent project you will have only dependencies for jars which are same for the child projects. for eg.

Parent pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.multimodule</groupId>
    <artifactId>multimodule</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>model</module>
        <module>presentation</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

child pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.multimodule</groupId>
        <artifactId>multimodule</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>presentation</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.multimodule</groupId>
        <artifactId>model</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

another child pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.multimodule</groupId>
    <artifactId>multimodule</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>model</artifactId>
</project>...
```

This sample is used for web application where you have separately model and presentation layer. Multimodule project can be easily created via Eclipse or Intellij Idea.

Comment: Okay, I have created a test setup mirroring your example. I have source folders `src/` next to the child poms, but nothing is compiled. I am getting JARs built, but with no class files in them. How do I compile or assembly:single the projects?

Comment: Use console -> go to folder with your project. Use `mvn package` . You can specify what package you want for eg. `<packaging>war</packaging>` If you use Intellij Idea you have all lifecycles directly in IDE for each modul separatelly.

Comment: @aib if your classes are located in `src`, you need to add `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>` in the `<build>` section of each pom.xml. But I would rather recommend to move your files to `src/main/java`. See more details in my answer.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Yes, thank you. I fixed that. I think I will move my source files as well.